# Vim fugitive plugin does not recognise git archive on Windows

Tags: windows, git, vim, vim-fugitive

I installed vim fugitive via pathogen plugin. Helptags created the tags for fugitive.

In the next step I set up a brand new git repo with git init, jumped into that folder, created a README.

In gVim I then run :Gstatus but the split window that opens is empty. :Gcommit tells me that the command git is spelled wrong.

I installed Git-1.7.9-preview20120201.exe for Windows 7 64Bit from here:

http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list

Can anybody bring me on the right track?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `git`command is not in the PATH environment variable. What happens if you invoke `git` from Windows command prompt?

msysgit installer provides you 3 options:

- Use Git Bash only: PATH won't be edited.
- Run Git from Windows Command Prompt: it will add Git to your PATH.
- Run Git and included Unix tools from the Windows Command Prompt: Git and several Unix tools will be added to your PATH.

So, you can re-install git with one of the two last options or add manually `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd` to your PATH.

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly the problem. I never thought of that since git bash always worked and was the only one I used. Regards